# Rails5 what on earth is this assignment.errors showing me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form I'm using for submission..I've got a gnarly method  "create_shift" in my controller to handle said form...but here is the catcher... have to use a preexisting database and the relations are....interesting

the form fails to submit with a "method_missing" error. Doing a assignment.errors gives me this output that I do. not. understand.

What on earth is this telling me? I have missing form fields? When I try to submit the form with "attendance_type" and "call_status_type" coded in via my "create_shift" I still get a different error which I'll list at the bottom of this post...

So first the error output I get with NO.."attendance_type" and "call_status_type" added in my "create_shift"...

[image]

_form.html.erb

```
<!--This is NEW action form-->

<%= form_for @assignment, :url => @my_url, remote: true do |f| %>

<!--  #FIXME need a fields_for 4 the volunteer_event-->

  <div class="">
    <div class="modal-body  d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-8 border-right">
        <section id="location-date-time-notes" class="flex">
          <% if @assignment.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@assignment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assignment from being saved:</h2>
              <ul>
                <% @assignment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <!--VOLUNTEER SHIFT-->
          <!--TODO: make this a partial under field_for-->
          <%= f.fields_for :volunteer_event do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'assignments/volunteer_shift_fields', vs: builder %>
          <% end %>
          <!--TODO: Volunteer Shift end -->


          <div id="time-row" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_time" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time:
            </label>
            <div class="col- p-2">
              <div class="myStartTime"  id="start_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :start_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col- p-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <div class="myEndTime"  id="end_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :end_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_notes" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notes:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 p-2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <span> Notes only get saved if a contact is assigned the shift, and get removed when the contact is removed from the shift.</span>
                <div class="">
                  <%= f.label :notes %>
                  <%= f.text_area :notes %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <!-- Contact Section-->
        <div id="contact_section">
          <% if @assigned_contacts &&  @assigned_contacts.length > 0 %>
            <h2>Previously Assigned Contacts</h2>
            <% @assigned_contacts.each do |c| %>
              <%= label_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "Are you sure you want to remove the currently scheduled volunteer, #{c.display_name} (##{c.id}), from the assignment(s)?" %>
              <%= check_box_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "replace", @replaced_contacts.include?(c.id) %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <input id="contact_element_prefix" name="contact_element_prefix" type="hidden" value="contact">
          <div class="name large flex-row">
            <%= f.label :contact_id %><%= f.text_field :contact_id %>
          </div>

          <div id="display-contact" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <% if f.object.contact_id %>
              <%= render partial: 'contacts/contact_display', locals: { contact:f.object.contact} %>
            <% else %>
              <div>no contact attatched- _form.html called</div>
              <%#= link_to 'Show Contact', contact_path(f.object.contact_id),  remote: true %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <!--    FIXME: replace this logic stack with AJAX-->
          <%#= contact_field("@obj", "contact_id",
        :locals => {:options => {
        :object_name => f.object_name.to_s,
        :field_name => 'contact_id',
        :on_display => 'display_disciplinary_notes(); display_contact_notes();'
        }}
                      ) %>
          <%= f.label :closed, "Is this slot closed?" %>
          <%= f.check_box :closed %>

          <!--Contact Section END-->
         
          <!--Attendance / Call Status start-->
          <% if f.object.id && f.object.contact_id %>

            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_attendance_type_id">Attendance:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "attendance_type_id",
                                             AttendanceType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },
                                             :include_blank => true) %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_call_status_type_id">Call status:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "call_status_type_id",
                                             ([["not called yet", ""]] + CallStatusType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }),
                                             :include_blank => false) %></div>

            </div>
          <% end %>
          <!-- Attendance / Call Status End-->

          <!-- LOCK VERSION-->
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <%= f.label :lock_version %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <%= f.number_field :lock_version %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- LOCK end-->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="edit_icons d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/edit/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="split"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Split</a>-->
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/copy/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="copy"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copy</a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <%#= link_to '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit'.html_safe, edit_assignment_path,  remote: true%>
          <!--            <a href="#" onclick="reassign(<%#= skedj.current.id %>); return false;" title="reassign"> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reassign</a>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= f.submit "Submit" %></button>
        <!--              <input id="assignment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update">-->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the Model

assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  # attr_accessor :volunteer_event ,:contact_id #why is this volunteer_event and not volunteer_shift???
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift
  has_one :volunteer_task_type, :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :contact ,optional: true
  validates_presence_of :volunteer_shift #belongs_to takes care of this now
  validates_associated :volunteer_shift
  belongs_to :attendance_type
  belongs_to :call_status_type
  validates_presence_of :set_date, :if => :volshift_stuck #belongs_to takes care of this now??
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift, allow_destroy: true

  delegate :set_date, :set_date=, :to => :volunteer_shift
  delegate :set_description, :set_description=, :to => :volunteer_shift

  has_one :contact_volunteer_task_type_count, lambda{||
    {:conditions => 'contact_volunteer_task_type_counts.contact_id = #{defined?(attributes) ? contact_id : "assignments.contact_id"}', :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts}
  }
  scope :date_range, lambda { |range|
    joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event)
        .where(volunteer_shifts: { volunteer_events: { date: range } })
  }
  scope :is_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) > ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :on_or_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) >= ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :not_cancelled, -> { where('(attendance_type_id IS NULL OR attendance_type_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM attendance_types WHERE cancelled = \'t\'))')}
  scope :roster_is_limited_by_program, -> {where("roster_id IN (SELECT id FROM rosters WHERE limit_shift_signup_by_program = 't')").joins(:volunteer_shift)}

  def real_programs
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift&.roster
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift.roster.limit_shift_signup_by_program
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.skeds.select{|x| x.category_type == "Program"}.map{|x| x.name}
  end

  attr_accessor :attendance_type_id


# TODO: find all time_range_s methods and either pull out to DRY or give unique names
  def time_range_s
    return "" unless start_time and end_time
    (start_time.strftime("%I:%M") + ' - ' + end_time.strftime("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def description
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.date.strftime("%D") + " " + self.time_range_s + " " + self.slot_type_desc
  end

  def roster_title
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.name
  end

def date
     return unless volunteer_shift
     volunteer_shift.date
   end

  #full calendar uses this method name....see the assignment.json.jbuilder
  def event_date
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.date
  end

  def slot_type_desc
    b = (self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type_id.nil? ? self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.description : self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type.description)
    b = b + " (#{self.volunteer_shift.description})" if self.volunteer_shift.description and self.volunteer_shift.description.length > 0
    b
  end

  def display_name
    ((!(self.volunteer_shift.description.nil? or self.volunteer_shift.description.blank?)) ? self.volunteer_shift.description + ": " : "") + self.contact_display
  end

  def cancelled?
    (self.attendance_type&.cancelled)
  end

  def attended?
    (self.attendance_type and !self.attendance_type.cancelled)
  end

  def contact_display
    if self.closed
      "(closed)"
    elsif contact_id.nil?
      return "(available)"
    else
      self.contact.display_name + "(#{self.voltask_count})"
    end
  end

  before_validation :set_values_if_stuck
  def set_values_if_stuck
    return unless (volshift_stuck || volunteer_shift)
    volunteer_shift.set_values_if_stuck(self)
  end

  after_destroy { |record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.destroy; else VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available; end}
  after_save {|record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.save; end}
  after_save { |record| VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available }

  def volunteer_shift_attributes=(attrs)
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.attributes=(attrs) # just pass it up
  end

  def volshift_stuck
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment
  end

#for fullcalendar
  def all_day_event?
    self.start_time == self.start_time.midnight && self.end_time == self.end_time.midnight ? true : false
  end
end
```

and controller

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #TODO refactor this line to be very specific

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
    # @assignments = Assignment.limit(20)
    # @assignments = Assignment.where(start: params[:start]..params[:end])
    @assignments = Assignment.date_range(params[:start]..params[:end])

  end

  # GET /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /assignments/new
  def new
    # @assignment = Assignment.new
    add_shift
    # @assignment.volunteer_shift.build
    @my_url = {:action => "create", :id => params[:id]}
  end

  # GET /assignments/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  def edit_old #dumb "stuff" from older app
    if @assignment
      @assignments = [@assignment]
    else
      begin
        @assignments = params[:id].split(",").map{|x| Assignment.find(x)}
        @assignment = @assignments.first
      rescue
        flash[:error] = $!.to_s
        redirect_skedj(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"], "")
        return
      end
    end
    @referer = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    @my_url ||= {:action => "update", :id => params[:id]}
    render :action => 'edit'
  end

  # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
  def create
    create_shift
    # @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
    #
    # # error wants contact.id not contact_id ???
    #
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   if @assignment.save
    #     format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
    #     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
    #   else
    #     format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    #     format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    #   end
    # end
  end

  def add_shift   # FIXME: evil brought over from old app
    ve = nil
    if !params["id"].blank?
      ve = VolunteerEvent.find_by_id(params["id"])
    else
      ve = VolunteerEvent.new
    end
    vs = ve.volunteer_shifts.new
    vs.program = Program.find_by_name("intern")
    #    vs.slot_count = 1
    vs.volunteer_event_id = ve.id if ve.id
    vs.volunteer_event = ve
    a = vs.assignments.new
    a.volunteer_shift = vs
    vs.stuck_to_assignment = true
    vs.not_numbered = true
    @assignments = vs.assignments = [a]
    @referer = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    @my_url = {:action => "create_shift", :id => params[:id]}
    @assignment = a
    # binding.pry
    # render :partial => 'assignments/new'
    # render :partial => 'assignments/edit' #<--original
  end

  def create_shift # FIXME: evil brought over from original code base
    # @fonso = @assignment.inspect
    ve = nil
    # Fixme: building volunteer shifts variable "vs" and associating with assignment
    if !params["id"].blank?
      ve = VolunteerEvent.find(params["id"])
    else
      if params["roster_id"].blank? || params["assignment"]["set_date"].blank?
        ve = VolunteerEvent.new # won't save
      else
        ve = Roster.find_by_id(params["roster_id"]).vol_event_for_date(params["assignment"]["set_date"])
      end
    end
    vol_shift = ve.volunteer_shifts.new
    vol_shift.stuck_to_assignment = true
    vol_shift.not_numbered = true

    #fixme: volunteer shifts variable "vol_shift" and association with assignment end
    call_status_type = CallStatusType.find_by_id(params["assignment"]["call_status_type_id"])  #fixme: this does not fix the problem
    attendance_type = AttendanceType.find_by_id(params["assignment"]["attendance_type_id"]) #fixme: this does not fix the problem

    # FIXME: vs.attributes=(params["assignment"]["volunteer_shift_attributes"]) # original needs to be rebuilt 4 this system
    h0 = {"volunteer_task_type_id" => params["volunteer_task_type_id"]}
    h1 = {"roster_id" => params["roster_id"]}
    h2 = {"program_id" => params["program_id"]}
    h3 = {"set_description" => params["set_description"]}
    #h4 = {"attendance_type" => attendance_type.name}            #fixme: this does not fix the problem
    #h5 = {"call_status_type" => call_status_type}          #fixme: this does not fix the problem
    hash_arr = [h0,h1,h2,h3]  #fixme: no h4 or h5

    volunteer_shift_attributes = hash_arr.reduce { |acc, h| (acc || {}).merge h }
    #binding.pry
    vol_shift.attributes = volunteer_shift_attributes #fixme: fracks up here but why?
    #fixme: vs.attributes fix end

    #FIXME: building variable - @assignments END
    assignment = vol_shift.assignments.new

    vol_shift = assignment.volunteer_shift

    assignment.attributes = (assignment_params) #<----magic happens here
    @assignments = [assignment]
    #fixme: building variable - @assignments END


    #FIXME: wtf is it and why is it?
    vol_shift.assignments = [assignment]
    vol_shift.set_values_if_stuck #fixme: <---- drill into this one
    binding.pry

    vs.assignments = []

    @success = assignment.valid? && vs.save #fixme: <--------what was the valid? error here?

    @assignment = assignment #fixme: <-----------------------@assignment is finally built here

    # fixme: the above lines are merging params from one into the other in the old app. to create the new volunteer_shift.

    respond_to do |format|

      if @success
        vol_shift = vol_shift.reload
          @assignment = a = vol_shift.assignments.new
          a.volunteer_shift = vol_shift
          #    a.volunteer_shift_id = vs.id
          a.attributes = (params["assignment"])
          @assignments = vol_shift.assignments = [a]

        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        vs.destroy
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  # def update -original
  #
  #   @assignment.update(assignment_params)
  # end


  def update
    unless params[:assignment]
      redirect_to :action => "index"
      return
    end
    @my_url = {:action => "update", :id => params[:id]}
    last_id = nil
    begin
      @assignments = params[:id].split(",").map{|x| last_id = x; Assignment.find(x)}
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash[:jsalert] = "The assignment (##{last_id.to_i.inspect}) seems to have disappeared or never existed. It is possible somebody else has modified or deleted it."
      rt = params[:assignment].delete(:redirect_to)
      redirect_skedj(rt, "")
      return
    end
    lv = params["lock_versions"]
    ac = params["assigned_contacts"] || {}
    @assigned_contacts = []
    @replaced_contacts = []
    ret = true
    @assignments.each do |as|
      as.lock_version = lv[as.id.to_s]
      if as.lock_version_changed?
        as.errors.add("lock_version", "is stale for this assignment, which means it has been edited by somebody else since you opened it, please try again")
        ret = false
      end
      if as.contact_id && as.contact_id.to_s != params[:assignment][:contact_id].to_s
        @assigned_contacts << as.contact
        unless ac[as.contact_id.to_s] && ac[as.contact_id.to_s] == "replace"
          as.errors.add("contact_id", "has been changed, please confirm below that the volunteer who is already assigned to the shift should be removed")
          ret = false
        else
          @replaced_contacts << as.contact_id
        end
      end
    end
    rt = params[:assignment].delete(:redirect_to)

    js_alert = nil

    if ! ret
      @assignment = Assignment.new
      @assignment.volunteer_shift = @assignments.first.volunteer_shift
      @assignment.attributes=(params[:assignment]) # .. ? .delete("volunteer_shift_attributes")
    end

    @assignments.each{|x|
      if ret
        @assignment = x
        bc = x.contact_id
        ret = !!(x.update_attributes(params[:assignment]))
        if bc != x.contact_id and x.first_time_in_area?
          alert = "#{x.contact.display_name} (##{x.contact_id}) has never logged hours for the #{x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type.description} task type. Please remind the volunteer of the requirements for this area."
          if x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event and x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes and x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes.length > 0
            alert += "\n\nSome suggested notes saved in the database for this event are:\n" + x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes
          end
          js_alert = alert
        end
      end
    }

    if ret && @assignment.contact and not @assignment.contact.is_old_enough?
      msg = "This volunteer is not yet #{Default['minimum_volunteer_age']} years old (based on their saved birthday: #{@assignment.contact.birthday.to_s}).\nPlease remind the volunteer that they must have an adult with them to volunteer."
      if js_alert == nil
        js_alert = msg
      else
        js_alert = msg + "\n\n" + js_alert
      end
    end

    flash[:jsalert] = js_alert if js_alert

    if ret
      flash[:notice] = 'Assignment was successfully updated.'
      redirect_skedj(rt, @assignment.volunteer_shift.date_anchor)
    else
      @referer = rt
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  # DELETE /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def destroy
    @assignment.destroy
    # NOTE: comment original out 4 now
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: "Assignment was successfully destroyed." }
    #   format.json { head :no_content }
    # end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
      @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def assignment_params
      #fixme: ,volunteer_shift_attributes: [:???, :???, :???] <--- insert this below?
            params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :set_date, :date, :date_range, :volunteer_shift_id, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color, :description, volunteer_shift_attributes: [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:set_date,:id,:destroy])
      # params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :set_date, :date_range, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color, volunteer_shift_attributes: [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:set_date,:id,:destroy])
    end
end
```

oh and the volunteer_shift.rb model

```
class VolunteerShift < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :roster_id
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  validates_presence_of :start_time

  has_many  :assignments

  belongs_to :volunteer_default_shift
  belongs_to :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :volunteer_event
  belongs_to :program

  has_many :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts, :primary_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id', :foreign_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id' #:through => :volunteer_task_type


  def validate
    errors.add("end_time", "is before the start time") unless self.start_time && self.end_time && self.start_time < self.end_time
  end

  def self.week_for_date(d)
    long_time_ago = Date.new(1901, 12, 22)
    difference = (d - long_time_ago).to_int
    ((difference / 7) % 2 ) == 0 ? "A" : "B"
  end

  def weeknum
    1 + ((self.date.day - 1) / 7)
  end

  def week
    VolunteerShift.week_for_date(self.date)
  end

  def slot_number=(a)
    write_attribute(:slot_number, a)
    self.not_numbered = (!slot_number)
  end

  def set_description
    self.description
  end

  def set_description=(desc)
    self.description=(desc)
  end

  def set_date_set
    binding.pry
    @set_date_set #fixme: <----- nil here...breaking here?
  end

  def set_date=(val)
    binding.pry
    @set_date_set = true
    @set_date = val
  end

  def set_date
    @set_date_set ? @set_date : self.volunteer_event.date
  end

  def set_values_if_stuck(assn_in = nil)
    return unless self.stuck_to_assignment #<---it's a boolean in the database
    assn = assn_in || self.assignments.first
    return unless assn
    self.start_time = assn.start_time
    self.end_time = assn.end_time
    return unless self.volunteer_event_id.nil? || self.volunteer_event.description.match?(/^Roster #/)
    # return unless set_date_set #fixme:<--- pry me...is this asking if date is set??

    roster = Roster.find_by_id(self.roster_id)

    if roster and !(set_date == nil || set_date == "")
      ve = roster.vol_event_for_date(set_date)
      ve.save! if ve.id.nil?
      self.volunteer_event = ve
      self.volunteer_event_id = ve.id
    else
      if self.volunteer_event.nil?
        self.volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.new
      end
    end

  end

  def shift_display
    time_range_s + ((!(self.description.nil? or self.description.blank?)) ? (": " + self.description) : "")
  end

  def time_range_s
    return unless self.read_attribute(:start_time) and  self.read_attribute(:end_time)
    (self.my_start_time("%I:%M") + ' - ' + self.my_end_time("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def my_start_time(format = "%H:%M")
    read_attribute(:start_time).strftime(format)
  end

  def self._parse_time(time)
    Time.mktime(2000, 01, 01, *time.split(":").map(&:to_i))
  end

  def my_start_time=(str)
    write_attribute(:start_time, VolunteerShift._parse_time(str))
  end

  def my_end_time(format = "%H:%M")
    read_attribute(:end_time).strftime(format)
  end

  def my_end_time=(str)
    write_attribute(:end_time, VolunteerShift._parse_time(str))
  end

  def self.range_math(*ranges)
   ... #cutting this out so the question can fit this post
  end

  def fill_in_available
    return if self.stuck_to_assignment #<-- it's a boolean in the database
    Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'] ||= []
    if Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].include?(self.id)
      return
    end
    begin
      Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].push(self.id)
      Assignment.where(volunteer_shift_id: self.id).select{|x| x.contact_id.nil? and !x.closed}.each{|x| x.destroy}
      inputs = [[(self.read_attribute(:start_time)), (self.read_attribute(:end_time))]]
      Assignment.where(volunteer_shift_id: self.id).select{|x| !x.cancelled?}.each{|x|
        inputs.push([(x.start_time), (x.end_time)])
      }
      results = self.class.range_math(*inputs)
      results.each{|x|
        a = Assignment.new
        a.volunteer_shift_id, a.start_time, a.end_time = self.id, x[0], x[1]
        a.volunteer_shift = self
        a.closed = self.volunteer_event.nowalkins
        a.save!
      }
    ensure
      Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].delete(self.id)
    end
  end

  after_save :fill_in_available

  def date
    self.volunteer_event.date
  end

  def date_display
    self.date.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y').gsub( ' 0', ' ' )
  end

  def date_anchor
    self.date ? self.date.strftime('%Y%m%d') : ''
  end

  def time_shift(val)
    self.start_time += val
    self.end_time += val
  end

  def left_method_name
    [self.volunteer_task_type_id.nil? ? self.volunteer_event.description : self.volunteer_task_type.description, self.slot_number].select{|x| !x.nil?}.join(", ")
  end

  def left_unique_value
    left_method_name
  end

  def description_and_slot
    ((self.volunteer_task_type_id || -1) * 1000) + (self.not_numbered ? 0 : self.slot_number)
  end

  def weekday
    Weekday.find_by_id(self.date.strftime("%w"))
  end
end
```

And now here is the error output I get WITH.."attendance_type" and "call_status_type" added in my "create_shift"...

(FYI: they are added by h4 and h5 to the hash in the create_shift method)...I get this error...

```
 ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute 'attendance_type' for VolunteerShift.:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h4 = {"attendance_type" => attendance_type.name} #fixme: this does not fix the problem is the cause of your problem here.
```

h4 get's wrapped up into an array and then the whole array get's shoved into `volunteer_shift_attributes`

```
volunteer_shift_attributes = hash_arr.reduce { |acc, h| (acc || {}).merge h }
```

Which in turn get's assigned to the `volunteer_shift` record that does not have an `attendence_type` column in your database. To get past this error just comment out the line

```
#h4 = {"attendance_type" => attendance_type.name} #fixme: this does not fix the problem is the cause of your problem here.
```

This leaves you with a logic error, you presumably need to set the `attendance_type` value on something, probably your assignment record but get that commented out and see where that leaves you, you can worry about the `assignment` after you have got past this error. That's a logic problem to solve not a coding error

Comment: UPDATED: I had an error on the original post..plus..I added both versions of the error responses I'm getting. For when h4 and h5 ARE added and when they are NOT added.